# Godot won't open vscode editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, godot, gdscript

I am trying to open a script written in gdscript from the godot game engine. I'm getting this error when I try:

```
 platform/windows/os_windows.cpp:2863 - Condition "ret == 0" is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_FORK
 editor/plugins/script_editor_plugin.cpp:2045 - Couldn't open external text editor, using internal
```

I've set my editor settings to use external text editor, and the external editor is set to vscode under mono/editor.

I've tried restarting windows, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue earlier. According to the godot docs, you have to point to the code.cmd file rather than the .exe file

Note, I am using godot 4.1 which may differ

See docs for reference: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/editor/external_editor.html

Answer (score 0):

I think a better option would be to have VS Code open in the directory you are working on and edit code instead of setting up an external editor. Also install godot-tools extension for VS Code which will provide functionality relating to Godot. I have linked a video instructing on using VS Code with Godot.
[The YouTube video](https://youtu.be/IqVpRYvVRKE)

Comment: Also error : " platform/windows/os_windows.cpp:2863 - Condition "ret == 0" is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_FORK" *might* be due to Windows having issues with Godot, not Godot itself.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I was able to resolve it by removing the quotes around the path for the vscode executable when configuring the external editor in godot.

Here is a link to the github page for the godot plugin:
https://github.com/godotengine/godot-vscode-plugin

Under the settings section, #4 mentions how to set the path, I removed the quotes from my path and it opened vscode when double clicking a script in godot.

**Not working path:**

```
"C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```

**Working path:**

```
C:\Users\Paul\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

Hope this helps someone, it was not mentioned in the docs that the path does not accept quotes. I expected quotes to be acceptable since there are spaces in it...